# Add secondary external server to domain

Tags: domain, windows-server-2012

I have an internal network that sits behind a router with one server that runs my local domain and a number of clients. The internal network uses a dynamic IP address. I have now just got a new external server hosted in a datacenter offsite for web hosting. I was wondering if there is a way to set up the new webserver to be part of the same domain as my internal domain? Both servers run Server 2012.

Hopefully I am making my question clear enough as I don't have much experience setting up domains.

Comment: Luke, I'm assuming you are referring to an Active Directory domain and not a domain in the "DNS namespace" sense. Does your hosting provider offer a VPN connection to your internal network?

Comment: Yes I'm referring to AD. The webserver is a VPS from which I can create a VPN to my internal network if that's what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a Windows perspective, there is no problem with this so long as the servers can communicate over the required ports. However, you absolutely should not do this without some form of VPN between the two physical sites.

Comment: Would a VPN from the webserver to the internal server be Ok or do you mean something more complex like a router that can make VPN connections?